# Kernel (Ker) doesn't lie in Image linear transformation (Im)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I need to find the lowest value of $a$ so that the kernel ($\ker$) doesn't lie in the image of the linear transformation (Im) with linear operator

$$ \left[\begin{matrix} a^3-8 & a-2 & 0 \\ 0 & a^2-4 & a^3-8 \\ a^2-4 & a^2-4 & a^2-4 \end{matrix}\right]$$

I don't quite understand what it means by Kernel (Ker) doesn't lie in Image linear transformation (Im). Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The kernel of this operator is the set of all elements in the domain that this operator sends to zero. The image of this operator is the collection of all elements that this operator maps on to. Can you rephrase your question with that in mind? Note that the domain and codomain are the same, so it does make sense to ask how the kernel and image intersect. So either the question means to determine what values of $a$ have kernel not laying completely in the image, or else so that the kernel doesn't intersect the image.

Comment: My question how kernel can not lie in image. I quite don't understand. I think that kernel always lies in image, no? I want to understand both cases.

Comment: I dont want answer but understand how to solve and why.

Comment: Tell me the image and kernel of the map:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
does the kernel lie in the image?

Also make sure you're not confusing image and codomain.

Comment: As much as I understand kernel - set of system solutions $$ \left[\begin{matrix} 1 &  0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]  \left[\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: So x = 0 and y is any value.

Comment: And image is the same as kernal, no?

Comment: @qweasdzxcqweasd No.  Think of a matrix that has a single column.  The image is the line spanned by the column.  The kernel is the hyperplane passing through the origin that is orthogonal to that line.

Comment: Image : x = any value not 0, y is any value?

Comment: * x = any value

Comment: Does it mean that (x,y) does not equal zero =>  kernel doesn't lie in image?

Comment: @qweasdzxcqweasd The kernel is $\{ (0,y)\mid y\in\Bbb R\}$ as you said, but the image is $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$, so these have only one element in common, namely $(0,0)$, so the kernel does not lie in the image, right?

Comment: @Frog Thank you. Does it mean that part of kernel  - (0,0) - always lie in image?

Comment: @Frog So what i need to do is find Kernel (basis vectors) which depend on parameter a, that find Image (basis vectors) so that Kernel doesn't lie in Image?

Comment: @qweasdzxcqweasd The kernel always lives in the domain, but the image always lives in the codomain, so it is possible that the kernel and image have empty intersection. It is only the fact that the linear operators in these cases are square matrices, so map from a space to itself. Linear operators always send zero to zero, so the zero vector of the domain is always in the kernel, and the zero vector of the codomain is always in the image. So for square matrices the intersection between image and kernel always has at least this.